# how to display data from database in wordpress with tablepress?

Tags: wordpress

I am making site with wordpress.
I am going to read data from database and display it at table using tablepress plugin.
But I do not know how to modify the tablepress plugin.
Help me.Thank you.

Comment: what you want to modify in tablepress plugin?? please explain some info.

Comment: you may use shortcodes in table press advanced editor option to show database dynamic data.

Comment: I want to read data from database and display it at table using tablepress plugin.
Now I found such code.
I don't know how to do modify tablepress plugin with that code.
thank you.